# Как правильно пишется: "малоеЖка" или "малоеШка"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно написать слово: "малоеЖка" или "малоеШка"?

Comment: Ориентируйтесь на очевидный образец "сыроежка" - там такой же способ словообразования.

Answer (score 2):

> ***"малоеЖка"*** или ***"малоеШка"***?

Правильно: ***малоежка.***

См. словари на [***Грамоте.ру.***](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0&all=x)

Answer (score 2):

**мал/о/е́ж/к/а**
[**Морфемно-орфографический словарь**](https://morphem_ru.academic.ru/34256)

Корень: **-мал-**; интерфикс: **-о-**; корень: **-еж-**; суффикс: **-к**; окончание: **-а**.

По такому же принципу образованы и другие сложные слова (с корнем **-еж-**):
сыр/о/еж/к/а, сладк/о/еж/к/а, сласт/о/еж/к/а, многоежка, фруктоежка, камнеежка .

Answer (score 1):

МАЛОЕЖКА, -и; мн. род. -жек дат. -жкам; м. и ж. Разг. О человеке, который мало ест. ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&ro=x&word=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0))

Answer (score 0):

**"Малоежка"**, конечно. 
Слово это лучше запомнить, как и "сыроежка", "быстроежка" и прочие. 
Объяснение есть, но оно достаточно сложное.
**Еж** - тут корень, вариант корня "есть", "е**д**а". Из "Д" звук "Ш" не возникает, если нет оглушения. Поэтому вторая основа в слове - ЕЖ/ЕД.

Но это для любителей языкознания и языковых олимпиад. Для остальных - словарь (ссылки есть в других ответах, не буду повторять).